# How do i binding context from tabbedpage to other pages from the CS code at Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, computer-science, tabbedpage

I have ListView and when a Item it opens a ItemTapped View Compose by 3 different pages, I want to recive in that pages the Object that i previusly tapped in the ListView to show it in a Text Label.

---

Sure ! These is my Tabbed Xaml Container

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <views:Page1>
        <views:Page1.BindingContext>
            <viewModels:MainViewModel/>
        </views:Page1.BindingContext>
    </views:Page1>
    <views:Page2>
        <views:Page2.BindingContext>
            <viewModels:MainViewModel/>
        </views:Page2.BindingContext>
    </views:Page2>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

These is my MainViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _selectedProduct;
    private string _purchasedProducts = "You purchased: ";

    public List<string> Products => new List<string>
    {
        "Computer", "Smartphone", "Tablet", "Keyboard", "Mouse", "Screen", "Headset"
    };

    public string SelectedProduct
    {
        get { return _selectedProduct; }
        set
        {
            _selectedProduct = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string PurchasedProducts
    {
        get { return _purchasedProducts; }
        set

        {
            _purchasedProducts = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public ICommand SelectCommand => new Command(() =>
    {
        PurchasedProducts += SelectedProduct + ", ";
        Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ContainerPage());
    });

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My MainPage were I have my ListView

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="40" Spacing="40">
    <Label Text="{Binding PurchasedProducts}" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}">
        <ListView.Behaviors>
                <local:ItemSelectedToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding SelectCommand}" />
            </ListView.Behaviors>
        </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

And Finally my Page1 contain in the TabbedPage where I want to get the ViewModel Data

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
      <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding PurchasedProducts}" />
      </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

When I run the project with the Debug tool I can see that in Page1

```
<Label Text="{Binding PurchasedProducts}" />
```

Im getting my selected value but then when the code runs by

```
Command.Execute(null);
```

it erase that value from the

```
<Label Text="{Binding PurchasedProducts}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Following MVVM, you should have a tabbed page View-Model which receives a reference to the Item you selected, then that tabbed page View-Model should have a hook into it's 3 children View-Models (the 3 tabs of the tabbed page), where it can somehow pass the reference of that item to its children, like through a constructor or a property.

```
TabbedView <=BindingContext= TabbedViewModel
    |                              |
    |                    selected item reference
    |                              \/
ChildView  <=BindingContext=  ChildViewModel
```

for Data Binding references:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics

for Tabbed Paged Binding examples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page